# Is SSRS more friendly to SQL users than Crystal Reports?

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008

So our ERP system has fairly limited SQL reporting tools, although it's pure SQL, write a query in a window, execute, and a report pops up.  Problem is, it's quite error filled, the exports are hideous and anything over 2,000 records may not display correctly.

So we decided to get Crystal Reports and frankly I hate the damn thing.  My SQL skills are practically of no use with this thing because everything is done with a report writer and you can't even edit basic SQL statements, you have to go through all these stupid hoops and loops just to make a basic change in your report.  I'm used to deleting a column name from my SQL statement, refresh, and boom, column gone.  In Crystal, deleting a column seems near impossible in an existing report, I spent like an hour researching and came up with nothing.  Every little task in Crystal seems to be ridiculously over complicated.

Basically, I just want a blank window where I can type real SQL code and get a damn report.  Can SSRS do this simple task?  I really don't give a damn about formatting, I just want data

Answer (score 1):

While SSRS is different, based on your description, I think you would run into similar frustrations. It does have a learning curve and simple changes to the SQL often require updates to the report design before you can even save the report, let alone run it.

Some alternatives to consider would be just using SSMS or embedding the SQL directly into an Excel workbook. If you have an instance of SharePoint available, the Excel Web Services is handy for sharing your workbooks. Any other reporting tool is going to have some level of formatting required to display the data.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look into SSMS

Comment: Okay, I just looked into Excel and wow.  Didn't know you could connect to your database and run queries from there.  I just connected to the database at work, it's awesome!!! Thanks